# Django media-files get 404 even when files definitely exist

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, django-urls, django-models

I realize this is an issue raised a lot in questions around here (and I read many of them), and it's not trivial to quickly explain the development-scenario, so I'll squeeze it into a specific simple-question which may explain everything, and I did not come across:

Regardless of how the templates and settings-parameters generate the final url, they end up successfully generating an image-url pasted in one of the rendered-pages (something like: localhost:8000/static/images/image-name.jpg) which I can see and everything's perfect.

The problem I have is in a different code-part (and app), where I keep getting 404s although the generated url seems to match my existing directory & files and I have no idea why it fails.
So what I did is simply copy the image I can't seem to load, into the same legit-folder (just pasted the file there), and modified the url (localhost:8000/static/images/new-image-name.jpg) - and got a 404 (even after reloading django).
I don't think this has to do anything with the db-objects (ImageField etc), since i'm only challenging the url-parse-and-conversion mechanism - and can't figure out why it works for some but not all images on the some path (same jpg format, image is loaded successfully in an image editor and in fact was drawn in mspaint).

(urls include urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() and that's the only static-relevant url-line as far as I can tell).

Any idea will be appreciated, I must be missing something about the url-decoding.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you leveraging the static files app in your installed apps? What are your STATIC/MEDIA_URL and STATIC/MEDIA_ROOT settings? Do you have DEBUG = True or False?

Comment: I was hoping that the clean and general question (of pasting-files-in-same-folder, but url-is-still-not-responsive-for-new-files) will spare these technicalities and will still lead me to the answer.. 

STATIC_URL is "/static/" and MEDIA_URL is "/static/media/".
(though these two - and mostly MEDIA_ROOT - are different between my server or windows-development-box, which is where i'm having this issue)

Comment: Is it just a difference between it working locally vs. remote? Or is the same behavior happening in both places?

Comment: Haven't tested this on the linux server (and would prefer to know what's going on, before). So you agree it is a strange behavior?

Comment: It seems odd that some of your files aren't being served and some are, if you're running locally and leveraging the staticfiles app.

Comment: Solved:

Thanks to your comment i figured something was wrong in my configuration. Seems that media-root was indeed linking to a previous checkout-path (and not current one), so i was placing files not where django was looking anyway (the images successfully loaded were in fact other exact images, from the parallel folder), when i fixed the path it all seems to work now.
Cheers.

Comment: Very good. Glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's happens only because web servers forward handling of all requests to application service(wsgi, uwsgi) which forward request to Django.

May be I'm wrong, but I think that application service shouldn't worry about static files. 
And because I have create separate location in web server(nginx in my case) config for static folder before location for application:

```
location /static/ {
    access_log        off;
    expires           max;
}

location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:///run/uwsgi/app/mysite/socket;
}
```